# Filter on collection with multidimensional array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection that is a multidimensional array. I need to filter only items with a specific color, however the color field is within a multidimensional. Normally it is as easy as `$collection->where('color','green')`.

How would I do this `WHERE` clause on something more complex?

```
[
    'product' => 'Desk', 
    'info' => [
            'namespace' => 'green', 
            'key' => 'blue',
        ],
        [
            'namespace' => 'orange', 
            'key' => 'red',
        ],
    ]
],
[
    'product' => 'Chair', 
    'info' => [
            'namespace' => 'green', 
            'key' => 'blue',
        ],
        [
            'namespace' => 'purple', 
            'key' => 'pink',
        ],
    ]
],
```

In this array how would I get all products that has the value `green` for the key `info['namespace']`?

`$collection->where('info['namespace']','green')` is basically what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you will have better results with the `filter` collection method (`where` doesn't seem to do nested very gracefully).

[Laravel Documentation on the filter method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter)

Example:

```
$greenNamespaceCollection = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {

    return collect($value['info'])->contains('namespace' 'green');
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to loop over `info[]` somehow since there are multiple elements in that array?

Comment: This worked, but you need to edit your answer. I needed to loop over `$value['info']` and wrap it in conditional logic. `if($info['namespace']) == "green" { return $value }`

Comment: Oh, my bad! I didn't read the structure properly (you might want to update the `info`, missing `[ ]`. I have edited the answer to combine `filter` with `contains`.

Comment: That’s even better! It’s just pseudo data, thanks for the heads up though.